# R function for calculating a 'cumulative difference'

Tags: r, difference, cumsum

I have a vector like

```
v <- c(76, 31, 33, 7)
```

and need to calculate its 'cumulative difference' resulting in

```
cumdiff <- c(45, 12, 5)
```

which is 76 - 31 = 45 and 45 - 33 = 12 and 12 - 7 = 5.

Is there an R function like `cumsum` or do I need to use a loop?

Thank you very much for your help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option using `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(`-`, v, accumulate=TRUE)[-1L]
#[1] 45 12  5
```

Or using negative of `cumsum`

```
v[1L] - cumsum(v[-1L])
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That was very fast and works perfectly. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
accumulate(v, `-`)[-1]
#[1] 45 12  5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this helpful solution. Sorry for the late response. Too many other duties.